# An error occurred (XMinioInvalidObjectName) when calling the PutObject operation: Object name contains unsupported characters

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I've the following class

```
class Foo:
    def value_to_filename(self, validated_data : dict):

        file_name = json.dumps(validated_data, cls=Encoder)
        file_name = self.convert_to_valid_s3_name(file_name)
        full_name = f"{file_name}.json"
        return full_name

    @classmethod
    def convert_to_valid_s3_name(cls, text : str):
        "value to cleaned filename"
        return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(text.encode()).decode()
```

when uploading this to s3 it raises object name contains unsupported characters even if it doesn't
measuring the name size it was less than 450 byte and max is 1024 so that can't be the issue
but when splitting the name and using each half separately to check what part of the string is invalid, both halves worked perfectly

example string:

```
path/path/path/eyJhZGRsick12456IDEsICJtb2RpZmllZF9ieSI6IDEsICJjaGF0X2lkIjogIiIsICJjcmVhdGVkX2F0IjogIjIwMjotMDMtMjQgMjA6MjU6MjkuNzY1NzM0KzAwOjAwIiwgIm1vZGlmaWVkX2F0IjogbnVsbDwgInT4cGUQOiAic2FwZm9rYXBma2FwZnNkcFtsZnNkYVsgbGFmcGFkc29mIGthc1tvWyBscWVhLWZwIGRzW3BscjJbM3IncWUseHouZiwsengvZix6eCA7LGFzLGZhcydmIiwgImNhcmVQcm92aWRlciI6ICJhb3BrZmFwZiIsICJzdGFydF9kYXRlIjogIjIwMjQtMDMtMTQgMSQ6MTE6NDcuNjAxMDAwKzAwOjAwIn1=.json
```

Using idrivee storage